# Call a Javascript function within an inline statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quick question: It's kind of tough to describe so let me just show an example.

Is there anyway to do this: (I'm using jQuery but this is a general javascript question)

$('div.element').offset().x;

$('div.element').offset() by itself will return {'x' : 30, 'y' : 180}, so I'm just wondering if there is any compact way of doing this without creating an extra variable.

Thanks!
Matt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you said, you can absolutely use this:

```
$('div.element').offset().left
```

OR

```
$('div.element').offset().top
```

Please note that jQuery's [`offset()`](http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/offset) returns `{ left: 30, top: 180 }` not an x/y pair like you said.

Comment: Ahhh. That's what tripped me up. Silly me - not looking at the documentation. Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

It will always create the object. I think you mean .top or .left instead of x/y?

```
>>> $('#jq-header').offset().left // 177.5
var coords = $('#jq-header').offset()
coords.left // 177.5
coords.top // 0
alert($('body').offset().left) // 0
```

http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/offset

Answer (score -3):

Apparently, you can do the exact thing you said: `$('div.element').offset().x;`.